# Cannot uninstall cordova -bash: uninstall: command not found

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ionic-framework, npm, installation

I am having a problem with my npm install. Whenever I attempt to run it, my terminal gets stuck on "fetchPackageMetaData error for cordova", for about 30 mins and eventually fails with a bunch of errors. I am trying to uninstall cordova, delete my node_modules folder and reinstall my dependencies, so I can run ionic serve. I am using AngularJS, with node.js and ionic. **However, when i run uninstall -g cordova, i get this error -b:uninstall: command not found.**

Comment: You need to run `npm uninstall -g cordova` command

Comment: this worked for me thank you!!

Comment: it says the packages were removed but when i run npm install i am still getting stuck on cordova

Comment: It's better to mention OS, NodeJS version, and what error you are getting. It may be due to a slow network or permission issue or you do not have enough disk. You should delete node_modules folder and then `npm clean cache` and then `npm install`